Modifying a default Windows 11-style .png in Delphi Firemonkey
I've been trying for a several hours to modify the appearance of an application, playing with the Style Designer.
I ended trying to modify the default image where the colors are grabbed. For this, when modifying a TStyleObject, I can see in the Object Inspector a property called SourceLink.
If I press the [...] button in this SourceLink, the BitmapLinks Editor is opened. There I can choose with a simple rectangle the color of the component.
It is making reference to a png called "Windows 11 Desktopstyle.png", and tht is the file I want to copy and modify with my colours, but I can not find it.

Any guess?

If a search of your hard drive does not find it, it is probably an embedded resource in the IDE itself or one of its packages.

Yes, that is what I did and I think it is embedded into the .style file. But I can’t believe there is no way I can extract it. This would be so easy to just replace with same dimensions with your custom colouring…
